# should I treat this json data file as object or array

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have the below posted json contents. I would like to fetch the data with volley.
my question is, should i treat it as JSONObject or JSONArray? i am asking this question because as shown below in the json data below it starts with `[` 
and ends with `]`

**code**:

```
this.mJSONObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, this.BASE_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

**json**

```
[
{
    "trends": [
    {
        "name": "#ChainedToTheRhythm",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23ChainedToTheRhythm",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23ChainedToTheRhythm",
        "tweet_volume": 48857
    },
    {
    },

    {
    },
    ..
    ..
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: It's an array of objects. `"trends"` it's also an array of objects. Check out [this](https://www.cheatography.com/mackan90096/cheat-sheets/json/) cool cheatsheet. You can also use [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/) json parser to easily see the objects/arrays.

Comment: When starting with `[`, it is a JSONArray. Next token is `{`, so this JSONArray contains 1 or more JSONObject.